# Images only render when delay 1 second then setState

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I got a problem when trying to load image async and render it and I need to set a delay for 100ms to setState anything to make image rendered but it only work with small amount of image but with much more images it needs much more than 100ms. Anyone have a solution for it. Thanks so much

```
this.props.callApi('GET', '/api/folders/' + child.id + '/files', null, this.props.token, (data) => {
                    console.log(data)
                    data.data.content.forEach(ele => {
                        fetch("/api/files/" + ele.id + "/blob")
                            .then((res) => res.blob())
                            .then((res) => {
                                childFolder.uploadFile.push(URL.createObjectURL(res));
                            });
                    })
                    arr.push(childFolder);
                    this.setState({uploadedLink: arr}, () => {
                        // this.setState(this.state)
                        // this.render();
                        // NEED TO SET DELAY TO IMAGE RENDERED
                        _.delay(() => this.setState({loading: false}), 100);
                    });

                })
```

Comment: The issue is that you are getting the images after you already called setstate, you need to call setstate after you got the images

Comment: @Ferrybig like u said the problem here is it still not make the image to blob url when I setState right?

Comment: @Ferrybig so can you tell me when should I setState. How to know when the iamge loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `onLoad` prop of image tag to handle the loaded state:

```
...
handleImgLoaded = () => {
   this.setState({ loading: false })
}

render(){
  const { uploadedLink } = this.state;

  return (
    <img src={uploadedLink} onLoad={this.handleImgLoaded} />
  )
)
```

Comment: Yeah thanks so much @gazdagergo. I have handled it :D

Comment: Yes, I have answered just 3 seconds after you managed it anyways. Thanks though :D

Comment: I spend all the time in the morning finding out the solutions. But when I see the suggestions from you guys. I know what I need to do. Thanks